# how to identify an element in a collection value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting this error messages when i run terragrunt apply.I need to be able to specify each element when creating SQS and DeadLetterQueue with the policy.I am unsure how to fix this issue.I want to find a way to reference individual DLQ directly with corresponding SQS to create the required resources

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "Cloudtrail_SQS_Policy" {
  for_each  = toset(var.sqs_queue_names)
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSQSInvocation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS":"*"},
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].arn}"

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{
    for_each  = toset(var.dead_queue_names)
    queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ[each.key].id

    policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DLQ Policy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS":"*"},
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ[each.key].arn}
```

```
Error Messages:

Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on iam.tf line 3, in resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "Cloudtrail_SQS_Policy":
│    3:   queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on iam.tf line 15, in resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "Cloudtrail_SQS_Policy":
│   15:       "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].arn}",
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on iam.tf line 15, in resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "Cloudtrail_SQS_Policy":
│   15:       "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].arn}",
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your entire code, as any changes will cascade to more errors. In your case, the best way to deal with your requirement is to use **map**, not `list` or `set`. You don't have to make your input variables a map if you don't want, though it would be easier. But keeping your input variables as they are, you can create `local.sqs_dlq_map` and use that:

```
locals {
  sqs_dlq_map = zipmap(var.sqs_queue_names, var.dead_queue_names)
}


resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{

    for_each                   = local.sqs_dlq_map
    name                       = each.key
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ[each.key].arn
        maxReceiveCount        = 2 #var.max_receive_count
    })

    #tags = var.default_tags
    
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{

    for_each                   = local.sqs_dlq_map
    name                       = each.value
   

    #tags = var.default_tags
}


resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "Cloudtrail_SQS_Policy" {
  for_each  = local.sqs_dlq_map
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSQSInvocation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS":"*"},
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS[each.key].arn}"
    }]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{
    for_each  = local.sqs_dlq_map
    queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ[each.key].id

    policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DLQ Policy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS":"*"},
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ[each.key].arn}"
    }]
}
POLICY
}
```

Comment: ,thank you so much for your reponse..I don't mind refactoring the whole code if it will get me to where I want to be. Will this line associate each SQS to the appropriate Deadqueue------- redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ[each.key].arn

Comment: @bibi I added DLQ to then answer

Comment: Thank you for your time very much appreciated. I will give you feed back tomorrow

Comment: it worked perfectly

Comment: thank you so much @Marcin